Make sure you use: <ion-refresher slot="fixed"> - Ionic 8 React
I have added  to my project but keep getting the error Make sure you use: <ion-refresher slot="fixed"> in my console and not working in the project.
<IonContent>
 <IonRefresher
  slot="fixed"
  onIonRefresh={handleRefresh}
  pullFactor={0.5}
  pullMin={40}
 >
  <IonRefresherContent
   pullingText="Pull to refresh"
   refreshingSpinner="circles"
   refreshingText="Refreshing..."
  ></IonRefresherContent>
 </IonRefresher>

/* rest of code */

</IonContent>



I have gone through all the documentation and through all the repo issues etc but can't find any solutons.

Had same issue here..

Same here, and I'm on Ionic v6

I have got this working by using the following:

useEffect(() => {
 const refresher = document.getElementById("refresher");

 if (refresher) {
  refresher.addEventListener(
   "ionRefresh",
   handleRefresh as unknown as EventListener
  );
 }

 return () => {
  if (refresher) {
   refresher.removeEventListener(
    "ionRefresh",
    handleRefresh as unknown as EventListener
   );
  }
 };
}, []);


<ion-refresher
 id="refresher"
 slot="fixed"
 onIonRefresh={(e: CustomEvent) => handleRefresh(e)}
>
 <ion-refresher-content />
</ion-refresher>

Seems the react version just doesn't work so until then, this seems to be a workable solution.
